# In need of a loop that will generate sixteen variables, to reduce length of my code

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a js form assignment where I need to take a string-date that is created from the form, and convert it to a different date format. I have written the code (although it may be ugly), but I can't figure out how to write an effective loop so I won't have to write the code for all sixteen variables it creates. - the variables are a month and year var for eight string-dates that I've changed to "Jun. 2015" format.

```
var dates = [enterDate,exitDate,enterDate2,exitDate2,enterDate3,exitDate3,enterDate4,exitDate4];
var months = ["Jan.","Feb.","Mar.","Apr.","May","Jun.","Jul.","Aug.","Sep.","Oct.","Nov.","Dec."];

var parts0 = dates[0].split('-');
var mydate0 = new Date(parts0[0], parts0[1] - 1, parts0[2]);
var year1 = mydate0.getFullYear();
var month1 = mydate0.getMonth();
month1 = months[month1];

var parts1 = dates[1].split('-');
var mydate1 = new Date(parts1[0], parts1[1] - 1, parts1[2]);
var year2 = mydate1.getFullYear();
var month2 = mydate1.getMonth();
month2 = months[month2];

var parts2 = dates[2].split('-');
var mydate2 = new Date(parts2[0], parts2[1] - 1, parts2[2]);
var year3 = mydate2.getFullYear();
var month3 = mydate2.getMonth();
month3 = months[month3];

var parts3 = dates[3].split('-');
var mydate3 = new Date(parts3[0], parts3[1] - 1, parts3[2]);
var year4 = mydate3.getFullYear();
var month4 = mydate3.getMonth();
month4 = months[month4];

var parts4 = dates[4].split('-');
var mydate4 = new Date(parts4[0], parts4[1] - 1, parts4[2]);
var year5 = mydate4.getFullYear();
var month5 = mydate4.getMonth();
month5 = months[month5];

var parts5 = dates[5].split('-');
var mydate5 = new Date(parts5[0], parts5[1] - 1, parts5[2]);
var year6 = mydate5.getFullYear();
var month6 = mydate5.getMonth();
month6 = months[month6];

var parts6 = dates[6].split('-');
var mydate6 = new Date(parts6[0], parts6[1] - 1, parts6[2]);
var year7 = mydate6.getFullYear();
var month7 = mydate6.getMonth();
month7 = months[month7];

var parts7 = dates[7].split('-');
var mydate7 = new Date(parts7[0], parts7[1] - 1, parts7[2]);
var year8 = mydate7.getFullYear();
var month8 = mydate7.getMonth();
month8 = months[month8];
```

===================================================

I still haven't gotten to the loop yet. I'm still trying to understand the map. So if I'm understanding this, the map iterates through the array of string-dates and converts them to date objects. So datesObjArr should now contain eight date objects. So wouldn't this work (yet, still no loop yet):

```
var dates = [enterDate,exitDate,enterDate2,exitDate2,enterDate3,exitDate3,enterDate4,exitDate4];
var months = ["Jan.","Feb.","Mar.","Apr.","May","Jun.","Jul.","Aug.","Sep.","Oct.","Nov.","Dec."];


var dateObjArr  = dates.map( 
    function(s){
        var parts = s.split('-');
        return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
    } );
}

var year1 = dateObjArr[0].getFullYear();
var month1 = dateObjArr[0].getMonth();
month1 = months[month1];

var year2 = dateObjArr[1].getFullYear();
var month2 = dateObjArr[1].getMonth();
month2 = months[month2];

var year3 = dateObjArr[2].getFullYear();
var month3 = dateObjArr[2].getMonth();
month3 = months[month3];

var year4 = dateObjArr[3].getFullYear();
var month4 = dateObjArr[3].getMonth();
month4 = months[month4];

var year5 = dateObjArr[4].getFullYear();
var month5 = dateObjArr[4].getMonth();
month5 = months[month5];

var year6 = dateObjArr[5].getFullYear();
var month6 = dateObjArr[5].getMonth();
month6 = months[month6];

var year7 = dateObjArr[6].getFullYear();
var month7 = dateObjArr[6].getMonth();
month7 = months[month7];

var year8 = dateObjArr[7].getFullYear();
var month8 = dateObjArr[7].getMonth();
month8 = months[month8];
```

Comment: No, you don't need 16 variables. You need one variable with an array.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will be better served by using `map` and return an array of `Date` objects

```
var dateObjArr = dates.map( function(s){
    var parts = s.split('-');
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
});
```

You can iterate this array and format them as needed.

Or you can return an array of year and month (name of month) itself

```
var dateObjArr = dates.map( function(s){
    var parts = s.split('-');
    var date = new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
    return [ date.getFullYear() : months[date.getMonth()];
});
```

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara yes, that is what I meant. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Using a map is outside of my expertise, and I can look it and learn it of course but is there a more elementary method? I ask because I wouldn't assume that my professor would expect to use a concept he hasn't taught yet.

Comment: @ChrisGaglioti map is as *elementary* as it can get in javascript. It is an Array method that allows  you to iterate an array and return a value against each value of the original array.

Comment: I still haven't gotten to the loop yet. I'm still trying to understand the map. So if I'm understanding this, the map iterates through the array of string-dates and converts them to date objects. So datesObjArr should now contain eight date objects. So wouldn't this work (yet, still no loop yet): IGNORE, TRYING TO ADD CODE

Comment: That is correct, though map is a **kind of** loop as well, just not exactly same :)

Comment: Please don't update the question like this. It makes the answer useless and pointless. That could be another question itself.

Comment: Then how would I get clarification where it would be necessary to post additional code?